# How to load records effectively in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a database of one million records with 50 columns. I have an ORM model of [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29). The problem is that my page size is 200 rows. But, I want to fetch only 5 records. How can I achieve it without using a criteria API?

Comment: On what criteria do you select these 5 records? How about using a HQL query? What do you mean with "page size"?

Comment: how is this related to struts/struts2 ?

Comment: Have you normalized your database?
A single table with 50 columns?
What about your entities? Do you have just one entity?

I don't think hibernate is a good tool for your case, just ignore hibernate an use direct JDBC or iBatis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `setMaxResults()` method from the [Query class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29).